# VSTO format word-footer to be left-bound

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, ms-office

im need to implement a way to one-click add a footer to a word document consisting of one line.
The first part needs to be the absolute Path to the document and it has to be left-bound. In addition to this, there has to be the actual page number aligned to the right.

This wasn't a problem on Excel; there I could use LeftFooter, CenterFooter, RightFooter.
On Word however there are no such properties to access.

**edit:** I found a semi-working solution which has some bugs in it and isn't properly designed because I could not find a proper way yet.

```
Word.Document doc = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument;
        foreach (Word.Section wordSection in doc.Sections)
        {
            Word.Range PageNumberRange = wordSection.Range;
            PageNumberRange.Fields.Add(PageNumberRange, Word.WdFieldType.wdFieldEmpty ,"PAGE  Arabic ", true);


            Word.Range footer = wordSection.Footers[Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range;
            footer.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter;
            footer.Tables.Add(footer, 1, 3);

            Word.Table tbl = footer.Tables[1];

            tbl.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = doc.FullName;
            tbl.Cell(1, 3).Range.Text = PageNumberRange.Text;
            /**/

            footer.Font.ColorIndex = Word.WdColorIndex.wdBlack;
            footer.Font.Size = 6;

            PageNumberRange.Text = "";
```

The problems with this one are: It never overwrites the exisiting footer. If it writes "document1 ... 1" and you click on it again, because you saved your document, it doenst change the footer. Furthermore: If you have multiple pages, every page except page 1 gets deleted.

I never imagined it could be so hard, to implement such an easy task.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach using styles

```
Document doc = this.application.ActiveDocument;
Section wordSection = doc.Sections[1];    
Range footer = wordSection.Footers[WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range;                              
footer.Fields.Add(footer, WdFieldType.wdFieldEmpty, @"PAGE \* ARABIC", true);                               
footer.Collapse(WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseStart);
footer.InsertBefore("\t \t");
footer.InsertBefore(doc.FullName);                                                          
footer.Font.Name = "Arial";
```

Comment: The main problem remains: How can I add this field, to the same line, where the path already stands?
Just adding this line results in overwirting my path with the page number.

Comment: you mean you want to clean existing footer before writing new one?

Comment: I have edited my original post, to show the problems I am facing.

Comment: when you add PageNumberRange.Fields.Add(PageNumberRange, Word.WdFieldType.wdFieldEmpty ,"PAGE  Arabic ", true) you delete out all pages, try if alternate approach edited above work for you